# Is there a way to use premium fonts in wordpress themes?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I have the HTML/CSS files done for a site and I'd like to CMS-ify it on Wordpress and sell it as a premium theme on ThemeForest. But the fonts I used are premium (Typekit) fonts, and not available on Google web fonts. Is there any way for people who buy the theme to use these fonts, or will they need to just use whatever fallback I designate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Typekit is not going to allow you to redistribute commercial fonts with your theme.

If possible, try to look for a close analog on Google Fonts.  In general the fonts on Typekit are of significantly higher quality than what you can find for free, but you might get lucky.